# handsontable virtual scrolling shades all columns when horrizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

Please have a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uF9JV/)

Basically in the code above I have some columns which are read-only and I am changing the background colour using the renderer. But when you horizontally scroll it applies the background to random cells. in the fiddle if you scroll horizontal, you can see the affect.

The code is as follows

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example1").handsontable({
      data: getCarData(),
      minSpareRows: 1,
      colHeaders: ["Car", "Year", "Chassis color", "Bumper color"],
      columns: [{
        data: "car",
        type: {
          renderer: myReadonlyRenderer
        },
        readOnly: true
      }, {
        data: "year"
      }, {
        data: "chassis"
      }, {
        data: "bumper"
      }]
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: I think that this was a bug and it's fixed in some of newest versions. Your jsFiddle looks fine for me.